# Нужно подключить фингерпринт в виде json файла в браузер selenium c#

Tags: c#, json, .net, selenium, fingerprint

Всем привет. Использую с# selenium. Есть файл  fingerprint.json и его нужно подключить к браузеру, который запускает selenium. Пытался сделать так: options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=\fingetprint.json"). Но так браузер не запускается. По сути, этот файл json - файл настроек браузера. Со шрифтами, юзер агентами и тд. Нужна помощь! Заранее спасибо

Comment: А что за браузер то?

Comment: Chrome Google!!